# Docusing i want to send additional file in same envelope id using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, docusignapi

i am using following code to send file with create envelope and signer and where to sign.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports DocuSign.eSign.Api
Imports DocuSign.eSign.Client
Imports DocuSign.eSign.Model
Imports Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc


Private Function DoWork(ByVal signerEmail As String, ByVal signerName As String, ByVal ccEmail As String, ByVal ccName As String, ByVal accessToken As String, ByVal basePath As String, ByVal accountId As String, ByVal templateId As String) As String
    Dim config = New Configuration(New ApiClient(basePath))
    config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
    Dim envelopesApi As EnvelopesApi = New EnvelopesApi(config)
    Dim envelope As EnvelopeDefinition = MakeEnvelope(signerEmail, signerName, ccEmail, ccName, templateId)
    Dim result As EnvelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelope)
    Return result.EnvelopeId
End Function


Private Function MakeEnvelope(ByVal signerEmail As String, ByVal signerName As String) As EnvelopeDefinition
Dim buffer As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Config.docPdf)
Dim envelopeDefinition As EnvelopeDefinition = New EnvelopeDefinition()
envelopeDefinition.EmailSubject = "Please sign this document"
Dim doc1 As Document = New Document()
Dim doc1b64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)
doc1.DocumentBase64 = doc1b64
doc1.Name = "Lorem Ipsum"
doc1.FileExtension = "pdf"
doc1.DocumentId = "3"
envelopeDefinition.Documents = New List(Of Document) From {
    doc1
}
Dim signer1 As Signer = New Signer With {
    .Email = signerEmail,
    .Name = signerName,
    .ClientUserId = signerClientId,
    .RecipientId = "1"
}
Dim signHere1 As SignHere = New SignHere With {
    .AnchorString = "/sn1/",
    .AnchorUnits = "pixels",
    .AnchorXOffset = "10",
    .AnchorYOffset = "20"
}
Dim signer1Tabs As Tabs = New Tabs With {
    .SignHereTabs = New List(Of SignHere) From {
        signHere1
    }
}
signer1.Tabs = signer1Tabs
Dim recipients As Recipients = New Recipients With {
    .Signers = New List(Of Signer) From {
        signer1
    }
}
envelopeDefinition.Recipients = recipients
envelopeDefinition.Status = "sent"
Return envelopeDefinition
End Function
```

i take working solution from this link [In Docusign using with Chilkat dll , how to pass templateRoles in json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63931690/in-docusign-using-with-chilkat-dll-how-to-pass-templateroles-in-json) by Inbar Gazit. i can send and get envelope id as return summary.

Now i want to add additional file which first file is signed by all signer. Same like again need to add 3rd file which 2nd file is signed by all signer in same envelope id. We use docusign connect to trigger event when signed by all signer.So we know document is singed by all signer or not.

In what way we can add additional document in same envelope id and send it again using Docusing dll. i have working c# project which download from docusign quickstart in that got 31 examples.

Note i am not use docusing rest or soap api.

Eg: We have machinery product company, First we send agreement related to product and prices to the signer, once get back agreement file signed by all, then we deploy and setup machinery in customer place once done ,then we send second acknowledge document to singer, once signed by all , filly we send finishing contract document. So we send all 3 files in same envelopeid in one by one.
Regards and Thanks
Aravind

Comment: why not add the additional file to the template? is it different each time?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, from above code we create envelope also dynamically without Template id and when send file i will get envelopeid in return summary, so here how to use templateid for add additional file ? and i enabled custom connect for send back document once signed by all. And above i updated description for what purpose need to send file in same envelope.

Comment: Yes templateid never change can use, but here we never use template, we create envelope and send files.

Comment: so you want to change code from 1 document to 2 documents?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want one more document, then it's simple, add/change this code:

```
Dim doc1 As Document = New Document()
Dim doc1b64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)
doc1.DocumentBase64 = doc1b64
doc1.Name = "Lorem Ipsum"
doc1.FileExtension = "pdf"
doc1.DocumentId = "3"
Dim doc2 As Document = New Document()
Dim doc2b64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer2)
doc2.DocumentBase64 = doc2b64
doc2.Name = "Second doc"
doc2.FileExtension = "pdf"
doc2.DocumentId = "4"
envelopeDefinition.Documents = New List(Of Document) From {
    doc1, docs2
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, actually above code will add 2 files at a same time when create and send envelope, my scenario is there can be multiples documents which are part of the same envelope but need to be sent to the recipients later after the first document signing process has been completed.

Comment: then you need two envelopes. Once an envelope is complete, you cannot send more documents for it.